# relacion directa en indirecta en base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

En que casos debería usar las relaciones directas e indirectas al modelar una base de datos.

Por ejemplo tengo un caso de este modelado, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
  usa relaciones directas(lineas continuas) e indirectas(lineas no continuas) pero cuando exporto el script y lo cargo el script en mi bd la tabla menuusuario tiene error,estoy seguro que es por el tipo de relación , De alli nace mi pregunta

Comment: Deberías 'graficar' un poco más tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿cuándo exportas el script de dónde a dónde? ¿qué error exactamente te da? ¿qué te hace pensar que es por el "tipo de relación"? La verdad, tengo años de trabajar con bases de datos y no se bien lo que quieres decir por _relación directa_ vs _relación indirecta_ (quizás te refieras a la cardinalidad de la relación, pero a mi el término no me suena). Simplemente una tabla está relacionada a otra o no.

Comment: ok.Vamos por partes; 1° genero el script usando worbench,2° carga el script a la bd usando el heidisql

Comment: Ahora en el heidiSql me sale un error que esta tabla esta mal formada y no se puede crear, pero aparentemente esta todo bien, estoy manejando una llave compuesta de los dos foraneas, pero aun asi me sale de esa manera, Pero lo que puedo notar es que estoy usando relaciones directas(lineas continuas), para relacionar esa tabla a comparacion de las demas que estan usando relaciones indirectas(lineas no continuas)

Comment: Por lo que veo el modelo esta todo bien; podrías especificar el tipo de error que te sale, por que no creo que sea por el tipo de relación así esta bien;

Comment: @JoeDiaz puedes agregar, además del error que obtienes, el código de la creación de tabla, así como cualquier código relacionado a su creación (ej: alteración para la creación de llaves a foraneas o índices). También indica la versión de mysql que estás usando.